# AssertionError for a test function

Tags: python, error-handling, pytest, bottle

I need to write a test function for a function. I am not able to understand what is going wrong. I am having an assertion error.

I have tried the following code. and reciving following error.

```
def test_file_upload():
        files= {'file' : open('files/questions/1/output.txt', 'rb')}
        global url
        url += '/check/1/output.txt'

>       assert requests.post(url, files = files).status_code == 200   # givin a error
E       AssertionError: assert 404 == 200
E        +  where 404 = <Response [404]>.status_code
E        +    where <Response [404]> = <function post at 0x7fd95ef0b268>('http://localhost:8080/check/1/output.txt', files={'file': <_io.BufferedReader name='files/questions/1/output.txt'>})
E        +      where <function post at 0x7fd95ef0b268> = requests.post

test_server.py:20: AssertionError
```

the function that needs to be tested receives a file from the form using the bottle.

here is the function that needed to be tested.

```
def file_upload(number):
    u_name = request.forms.get("username")  # accepting username
    uploaded = request.files.get("upload").file.read()
```

Comment: `AssertionError` means that the condition you `assert` is not true. That means your test suite has discovered a bug in your code. In this case -- the response code you expect is `200`, but you get a `404`

Comment: @Jytug I see that but, how can I debug it?

Comment: you need to check why the server at `url` at path `/check/1/output.txt` returns a 404

Comment: i am using the following function
``` 
@app.post("/check/<number>")
def file_upload(number):
    uploaded = request.files.get("upload").file.read()